# How to get the list of Swing UI components added dynamically through paintComponent

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to generate DOM tree of Swing application. I'm using `getComponents` method in recursive manner to get all the components.

But I couldn't get child component of one the custom control (using above mentioned way) which adds the controls in `paintComponent` method with the help of `CellRendererPane`. I don't have access to modify this custom control. I have the code replica of that custom control (MyComponent).

Can someone provide a suggestion or input to solve this problem?

Class `CustomPaint`:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CustomPaint {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MyComponent());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Class `MyComponent`:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.CellRendererPane;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MyComponent extends JComponent {

    CellRendererPane cellRendererPane = new CellRendererPane();

    public MyComponent() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        add(cellRendererPane);
        cellRendererPane.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250, 200);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Label label = new Label("Custom Label");
        label.setVisible(true);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        cellRendererPane.paintComponent(g, label, this, 10, 30, 100, 50, true);
        cellRendererPane.removeAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking - that's not how (painting) should be done. The `paintComponent` method (which should be `protected`) is creating a series of short lived objects, which could have an impact on the performance of the system.  Since the component is never "added" to anything there is no way to "get" it - the system is just "rubber stamping" the component's output onto it's surface

Comment: in other words: you __must not__ change the state of a component during the painting process (that is: in any of the paintXX methods) If you really need custom painting, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html